# Python - Calling a class as a parameter

Tags: python

I'm quite new in Python, but googling around did not match any answer for it .

I created a module, containing 10 GUI buttons classes. To use a button I write in code `ButtonLib.TypeA(**kwargs)`, `ButtonLib.TypeB(**kwargs)` and so on.
`kwargs` is same for all buttons.

Buttons ( amount and type ) are selected by user (stored in `button_type_vector`) and not known in advance.

I wish to know if there is a way writing code more efficiently rather than:

```
for x in button_type_vector:
    if x == 'TypeA':
        ButtonLib.TypeA(**kwargs)
    elif x== 'TypeB' :
        ButtonLib.TypeB(**kwargs)
```

and so on.

by efficiently I mean something like:

```
for x in button_type_vector:
    ButtonLib.x(**kwargs)
```

thnks

Comment: I don't quite understand your code. Iterating over `range` produces _integers_, but you're comparing `x` to _strings_. Shouldn't you be iterating directly over `button_type_vector`?

Comment: @ChristianDean -sorry. fixing it

Comment: It is not Python, but rather OOP field. You should define BaseButton class with abstract .TypeX method, and use this class as parent for every Button Type, assigning specific function to .TypeX in the constructor. Then you just call YourButton.TypeX(**kwargs)

Comment: @ChristianDean. Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Eh well, after I had finished posting my answer, I realized that this was probably a pretty common duplicate question. So I figured I should vote to close instead of answering it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't think it would've done much harm if I had keep my answer posted, but I deiced since nobody had responded to it yet, I should do the "right" thing to do.

Comment: @ChristianDean the link given give a solution in case I seek to get or set attr value, in my case I wish to create a class obj from a module , containing 10 different classes

Comment: @Guy.D. The piece of information you are missing seems to be that a module is an object that has attributes just like any other. You can access them by name using `getattr` just like the answer to the dupe suggests.

Comment: @ChristianDean. I think you should reinstate your answer, if only to save OP the additional confusion. While it will pay in the long run to have them think it out on their own, your answer is a great demo for the fact that modules are just another type of Python object. There is nothing exceptionally magical about them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Alright, I see your points. It's up again ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function to access attributes of an object using strings:

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError) is raised.

```
for x in button_type_vector:
    getattr(ButtonLib, x)(**kwargs)
```

As mentioned by @MadPyhisist, modules are not some kind of magical object, and thus can be used with like any normal object could be `getattr`.

Comment: thank you - what was missing was the `(**kwargs)`

Answer (score 1):

You could define a dictionary (preferably inside your module):

```
buttons = {
    "TypeA": TypeA,
    "TypeB": TypeB,
    …
}
```

and then call the entry:

```
ButtonLib.buttons[x](**kwargs)
```

If your button classes have a function returning their name, you could also define the dictionary like this:

```
buttons = {
    button_type.name: button_type
    for button_type in [TypeA, TypeB, …]
}
```

More advanced: Python stores the name of a class in `.__name__`.
Even more advanced: You could get the elements of the module with `getattr(ButtonLib, name)`. But this might impair readability.

Comment: Thanks for you answers!! Can you please explain more about advanced way?

Comment: My final code included both your answer and deans. 
Thank you !!!!